# Icon is not displayed in lwc

Tags: lightning

icon does not appear on page

```
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-doctype-xml" title="Description of icon when needed">
      <svg class="slds-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/doctype-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#xml"></use>
      </svg>
      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Description of icon when needed</span>
    </span>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use lightning:icon?

Comment: I want to use Column sorting.
https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**added based on comments:**

`SVG` is used only for the icons not available in [standard lightning icons](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/). [All these icons](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/icons/) can be used in `lightning-icon`. For the icons which are not available as standard in `lightning design system`, you need use option-2/3 below (through SVG - but it will be quite rare that you need something not already available in lightning)

---

For using icons, below are the options preference wise ordered:

**1. Use [lightning-icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/example)**

```
<template>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="action:approval" alternative-text="Approved" ></lightning-icon>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="doctype:audio" alternative-text="Audio file" ></lightning-icon>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:event" alternative-text="Event" ></lightning-icon>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:connected_apps" alternative-text="Connected" ></lightning-icon>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:warning" alternative-text="Warning!" variant="warning"></lightning-icon>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:error" alternative-text="Error!" variant="error"></lightning-icon>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:image" alternative-text="Utility image" ></lightning-icon>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="doctype:image" alternative-text="Doc image" ></lightning-icon>
</template>
```

**2. Use SVG in LWC template and use it directly.** (you can provide `api` attributes for dynamic nature)

mysvg.html:

```
<template>
    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"></rect>
        <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green"></circle>
        <text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">SVG</text>
    </svg>
</template>
```

Then use it wherever you need:

```
<template>
    <c-mysvg></c-mysvg>
</template>
```

**3. Upload SVG in [static resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_svg_in_component) and reference it in LWC JS.**

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import SVG_URL from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/svg_url';

export default class myComponent extends LightningElement {
    get svgURL {
        return SVG_URL;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <use xlink:href={svgURL}></use>
    </svg>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Why can not I use according to the instructions?
https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/icons/

Comment: added in answer

Comment: Method 3 does not seem to work in my LWC. It outputs `<use xlink:href="#httpssandbox1examplecs100forcecomcustomersresource1586165694000exampleiconhome"></use>`. It seems to sanitize the Url string. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Michael, you may be not importing the resource correctly

Comment: I thought I was doing it according to the docs: `import customSR from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/example_icon_home'`, where `example_icon_home` is a zip file static resource.

Answer (score 9):

You can add `/apexpages/slds/latest` in `xlink:href` to resolve icon rendering issue. Here is code which show user icon.

```
<span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_circle">
      <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-user" title="Description of icon when needed">
        <svg class="slds-icon" aria-hidden="true">
          <use xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#user"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Description of icon when needed</span>
      </span>
    </span>
```

Comment: But why should we even use like this when these standard icons are available through "lightning-icon" ?

Comment: Yes. It is advisable to use lightning:icon. But my answer to resolve his issue.

Comment: Just commenting in case others come across this: This is still the only way to get icons to work in this specific case. Can't find anywhere in their docs that mention the extra `/apexpages/slds/latest/` part of the href path, but it DOES work for me.